# Inverting Linear System of Inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, linear-programming, functional-inequalities

I have $6$ integral variables, $m,z,p, m',z',p'$. I have a set of three inequalities:

$$m\leq m' \leq p+m$$
$$m \leq m'-z' \leq p+m$$
$$2p+2m+z \leq 2m'+p'\leq 2p+2m+z$$
(The last one is an equality).

Or in Matrix format

$
\begin{bmatrix}
m  \\
m \\
2m+2p+z \\
\end{bmatrix}
\leq
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & -1 & 0 \\
    2 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
m'\\
z'\\
p'\\
\end{bmatrix}
\leq 
\begin{bmatrix}
m+p\\
m+p\\
2m+2p+z\\
\end{bmatrix}
$

I am trying to solve this system to bound $m',z',p'$ **individually** in terms of $m,z,p$. Meaning, I want an expression as:
$
{\bf f}(m,z,p)\leq \begin{bmatrix}
m' \\
z' \\
p' \\
\end{bmatrix}\leq {\bf g}(m,z,p)
$
How can I invert this system?

$$$$

Alternatively, I want a change of basis from $m',z',p'$ to an **orthogonal** basis $l,m,n$ such that
$
{\bf f}(m,z,p)\leq \begin{bmatrix}
l \\
m \\
n \\
\end{bmatrix}\leq {\bf g}(m,z,p)
$
again holds.